# I'm trying to add onClick into fragment but it's unable to find button id

Tags: android, fragment

I've implemented onClickListener but inside onCreateView() it's unable to find the button's id and i.e "myButton"

My Code is:

```
public class Category extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View view;Button b;
public Category() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container,false);
    b=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

My fragment_category.xml is as below it's containing one button and a textView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="layout.Category"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="135dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="208dp" />
```

Comment: How does your fragment xml look like?

Comment: add here also your R class import

Comment: Sir I've added the xml file please check it @MuratK.

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating "fragment_category", but you said you posted "fragment" xml code.

You're most likely not inflating the correct layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was there in IDE after some rectifications the error is sorted out.